# Does good deeds come to a person working an office job at a charity?

Tags: sadaqah, deeds

I know that giving charity or doing charity gives a person good deeds.

But if someone works an office job at a charity (for example being a graphic designer to design a poster for the public), does the one working get good deeds too?

I am thinking of working for a charity (I get paid as a graphic designer) and was just curious to know if I would get good deeds from Allah working in the office of the charity.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sister, if you become a graphic designer then be careful about drawing animals or humans, that's forbidden because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, according to the saheeh hadeeth: “Every image maker will be in the Fire.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most severely punished of people on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers, those who tried to imitate the creation of Allaah.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The makers of these images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and they will be told, ‘Give life to that which you have created.’”

But if you draw inanimate beings, that's halal.
I'm not sure about this, but I found a similar case. It's the case with a muezzin, I heard that a muezzin will get all the good deeds of those who pray with him. Based on that, in shaa Allah you will get the same good deeds as the donors that were attracted by your advertisements. Without subtracting from any of theirs because:

Jareer ibn 'Abdullaah al-Bajali (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: 'Whoever starts a good thing and is followed by others, will have his own reward and a reward equal to that of those who follow him, without it detracting from their reward in any way. Whoever starts a bad thing and is followed by others, will bear the burden of his own sin and a burden equal to that of those who follow him, without it detracting from their burden in any way.'" (Reported by al-Tirmidhi, no. 2675. He said, This is a saheeh hasan hadeeth)

Jazak Allah khayran,

And Allah knows best.